# RSpec authorization testing with raise_error not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cancan, rspec-rails

I'm trying to test how a not logged in user behaves like this

```
  describe "not logged in user" do
   user_no_rights

    it "can't access action index" do
      expect(get :index).to raise_error(CanCan::AccessDenied)
    end
  end
```

The output when i run rspec

```
  Failure/Error: expect(get :index).to raise_error("CanCan::AccessDenied:You are not authorized to access this page.")
     CanCan::AccessDenied:
       You are not authorized to access this page.
```

So it looks like the correct execption is raised, but why is the spec not passing?

Comment: In the case of raising an error `expect` might need to be passed a block: `expect{ get :index }.to raise_error(CanCan::AccessDenied)`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've changed my spec to:

```
 describe "not logged in user" do
   user_no_rights

    it "can't access action index" do
      expect{get :index}.to raise_error(CanCan::AccessDenied)
    end
 end
```

and it works. Kudos to Thomas! :-)